# Склеивание слов minifyHTML

Tags: html, gulp

Столкнулся с проблемой при минификации HTML, некоторые слова между которыми есть `<br>` - в моб версии делаем ему `br { display: none }`. И вместо `Привет мир!`, получаем слитно `Приветмир!`.

Кто-то сталкивался? Как бороться кроме как визуальной проверки всего контента и в местах где слилось добавлять вручную пробел типа `&#32;`

```js
gulp.task('minifyHTML', function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*.html','src/**/*.php'])
   .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(htmlmin({
     collapseWhitespace: true, 
     ignoreCustomFragments: [ /<%[\s\S]*?%>/, /<\?[=|php]?[\s\S]*?\?>/ ]
 }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Может лучше gzip использовать для сжатия контента?

Comment: с помощью .htaccess? пользуюсь) просто вариант с минификацией стал интересен)

Comment: Кеширование транслированных шаблонов, минификация, объединение набора файлов в один - это "костыли". По крайней мере, вместо минификации используйте сжатие, как предлагает @Buka.